# Open XML SDK: Programmatic text changes not tracked

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using Open XML SDK. I am performing some text changes. When I look at the output file, it has the changes but they are not tracked.

Here is my code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\Test.docx", true))
{
    var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var paras = body.Descendants<Paragraph>();

    foreach (var para in paras)
    {
        foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
        {
            foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
            {
                if (text.Text.Contains("Lorem"))
                {
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace("Lorem", "Lorem2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Track changes only works in the Word UI, when the user is editing.

If you want changes you make on the closed file to show up as revisions you need to look at how revisions are handled in the Word Open XML. I suggest you create a very simple document, turn on Track Changes, make an insertion, save, close and then open the document in the Open XML Productivity Tool to see the underlying XML as well as the code necessary to create the document (with the tracked change).

Answer (score 1):

The top-line message is that you should have a look at the [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools).

The [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) is a very low-level library for manipulating Open XML markup. It does not provide any abstraction whatsoever, meaning that you are required to create any and all markup yourself, using either the strongly typed classes provided by the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) or, to mention one other example, Linq to XML in conjunction with the [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) library. The latter provides more powerful tools for various use cases.

For example, the Open XML SDK provides strongly typed classes such as `Paragraph`, `Run`, or `Text` to represent Open XML elements such as `w:p`, `w:r`, or `w:t`. It also provides the strongly typed classes `InsertedRun`, `DeletedRun`, or `DeletedText` to represent revision markup such as `w:ins`, `w:del`, or `w:delText`. As mentioned above, you need to use those strongly-typed classes to create the desired markup.

So say you have the following document:

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

If you replaced `Lorem` with `Lorem2` with revision markup, the result could look like this:

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:del w:del w:id="0" w:author="Thomas Barnekow" w:date="2019-12-09T00:14:00Z">
        <w:r>
          <w:delText>Lorem</w:delText>
        </w:r>
      </w:del>
      <w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Thomas Barnekow" w:date="2019-12-09T00:14:00Z">
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Lorem2</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:ins>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> ipsum dolor sit amet</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The good news is that the [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) library contains the `OpenXmlRegex` utility class that produces the required markup for you.

Comment: thank you for your valuable feedback, it make sense to me. Also, I have switched to Open-XML-PowerTools. It would be great if you can tell me how I can use OpenXmlRegex to achieve this?

Comment: @PrateekPandey, have a look at Eric White's web site (e.g., http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/openxmlregex-developer-center/) or the Open-Xml-PowerTools GitHub repository. You will find examples there.